# activating xscreensaver by cronjob

Tags: linux, cron

linux users,

could you tell me if and how i can activate xscreensaver by a cronjob?
As background information i have to get off the pc every hour (for health reasons)- i thought it would be easiest to do this with cron.

```
50 * * * * /usr/bin/xscreensaver-command -activate
```

does not work as expected - syslog logs activity but i don't see one.
i also wont get a terminator (terminal emulator) started.
is there a way to start a gui/display program with cron ?

thanks in advance
 ε/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X applications require certain environment variables to be set, in order to point them to the right display. Try:

```
50 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xscreensaver-command -activate
```

If this doesn't work, you may need some sort of XAUTHORITY environment variable as well - check from within your GUI session to see if there's such a variable set, and replicate it here.

Comment: thanks for the swift answer - can you enlighten me some more about the XAUTHORITY env-variable $XAUTHORITY points to /tmp/.gdm13HQ1V but what do i have to set?

Comment: the question was answered in another forum - it was `50 * * * * export DISPLAY=0 && /usr/bin/xscreensaver-command -activate` but thanks anyway